# How to animate IsChecked property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have custom control with number of  ToggleButtons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ISA88Buttons}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ISA88Buttons}">
          <Border x:Name="PART_Border" 
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ISA88States">
...
                 <VisualState x:Name="AbortingState" Storyboard="{StaticResource sbAbortingState}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="AbortedState" Storyboard="{StaticResource sbAbortedState}" />
...
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<StackPanel Margin="1" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
...
<ToggleButton x:Name="PART_Button_Abort" 
                            Margin="1"
                            IsChecked="False"
                            IsThreeState="True"
                            Tag="Abort">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                      <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                          <Border x:Name="border" 
                                  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                  Background="{StaticResource NormalAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                              <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                              <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="sb">
                                  <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{StaticResource PressedAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.25" Value="{StaticResource NormalAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.5" Value="{StaticResource PressedAbortButtonDrawingBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                  </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                              </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                      </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                  </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
              </ToggleButton>
...
</StackPanel>
          </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

And Storyboards:

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="sbAbortingState">     
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Button_Abort" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>

  <Storyboard x:Key="sbAbortedState">
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Button_Abort" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
```

When my control in Aborting state, button Abort is blinking, but when i change state to Aborted the error is raises:

> Cannot animate the 'IsChecked'
>   property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton'
>   using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames'

How can I animate this property using Storyboard between **three** values: `true, false and {x:Null}`, not only `true and false`.

Comment: Please change your accepted answer to the one you posted, rather than the one you have marked as accepted now. That will help others find the solution that actually works. The currently accepted answer does not and cannot work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't really be setting a Boolean value using a ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation, rather it should be a BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation with a DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame keyframe.

So your markup would be:

```
<BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />
</BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
</BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
</BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Why do we need this `<DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />` ? Cause bool by default has false value

Comment: The question asked how to animate between three states, so I provided the markup for doing that.  If you don't think you need it for your particular application then try it without - less code is better!

Comment: I have come across this answer while investigating a related but different problem, and I'm confused by the code above. In particular, I don't see how you get `Value="{x:Null}"` to work. When I try that, I get an error in the XAML: `"The type "Boolean" does not support null values."` Which makes sense to me, since `Value` property has type `bool` and not `bool?` (i.e. `Nullable<bool>`). How could the above work? Is there in fact a way to animate a _nullable_ Boolean value?

Comment: FWIW: one can use `{x:Null}` when applying `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, as described in the other answer. I just don't see how you get the above code to work.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution. If you want to set bool? property in XAML you should do so:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: See the answer with BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames, that is the correct approach.

Comment: @ChuckRostance: you cannot use `{x:Null}` with `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. The other answer that suggests using that doesn't work as claimed, but the above answer does. Given that the OP is the one who wrote this answer, they ought to mark _this_ one as accepted, not the other.